# Conditional for matching generic nullable numeric types

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, types, nullable

Given a type `T`, is there any way to write something equivalent of

```
if (typeof(T).ImplementsProperty(MaxValue))
{
    return T ?? typeof(T).MaxValue;
}
else
    return T;
```

Note that I don't need a generic type constraint on the class or method, I just need a conditional in the method body. `T` in this case can be any `IComparable`. I'm trying to get null numeric/date types to be ordered with the nulls occurring last.

**Edit:** Sorry there is an error in the above syntax as pointed out by Ray. It should be returning `value ?? typeof(T).MaxValue` given a `T value` or something like that. Hope thats clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for me for nullable, value and reference types:

```
public T GetSelfOrMaxValue<T>(T value)
{
    var t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) ?? typeof(T);
    var fi = t.GetField("MaxValue");
    if (fi != null && fi.IsStatic && fi.FieldType.Equals(t))
    {
        return (T)fi.GetValue(null);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly a problem. You can't return T which is a Type Parameter. It would be equivalent to `return int` which is invalid.

But you can see if T has a `MaxValue` property and call it if it does. The below code checks for the static property called `MaxValue` and calls it (and assumes it's an int).

```
Type type = typeof (T);
var propInfo = type.GetProperty("MaxValue", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
if (propInfo != null)
    return (int)propInfo.GetValue(null, null);
```

I assume you want something like this:

```
    public static T GetValueOrMax<T>(T value) where T:IComparable
    {
        if (value != null)
            return value;

        Type type = typeof (T);
        var propInfo = type.GetProperty("MaxValue", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        if (propInfo != null)
            return (T)propInfo.GetValue(null, null);

        return value;
    }
```

But this will have it's own problems, if you pass an int in, it will never be null and it will always return `value`. If you pass a nullable int in, then it won't implement MaxValue (actually you can't pass a nullable int, since it doesn't implement IComparable).

A where clause of where `T:class, IComparable` may be the most appropriate.

Another option would be to change the check at the beginning to be

```
if (value != default(T)) 
    return value
```

But then passing 0 would return the MaxValue not 0, which may not be what you want.